# Can I build a new github pages deployment without using the github website?

Tags: linux, bash, github, github-pages, github-api

I'm building a tool to automate GitHub pages deployment through a script and am curious if there's a way to deploy a new repo to pages without having to open the website's repo settings to do so.

```
curl -u {username}:{access_token} -X POST -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repo}/pages
```

This is what I'm currently doing, but it seems to work for *rebuilds* only and not for new ones that have never been built before.

So it throws the following error:

```json
{
  "message": "The repository does not have a GitHub Pages site. See https://docs.github.com/v3/repos/pages/",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#request-a-github-pages-build"
}
```

I've tried a other few options too (octokit, gh, hub, etc) but can't find anything that can help me solve my problem. Is browser automation with something like Selenium the only choice left?

Would appreciate any help related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

After messing around with it for some time I managed to find a fix that worked for me.

```sh
curl -u {user}:{token} -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.switcheroo-preview+json" https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/pages
```

Basically had to update the custom media type to match the latest for Pages API preview (`vnd.github.switcheroo-preview` at the moment, see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-github-pages-site-preview-notices).

Upon changing it got response: `{"message"=>"The gh-pages branch must exist before GitHub Pages can be built.", ...}` so created `gh-pages` branch in my script as well.

```sh
git checkout -b gh-pages
```